# getting ClassCastException when calling getSession().get() in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is very weird to me...

so this...would throw `ClassCastException`

```
MyStatus object = Main.getSession().get(MyStatus.class, 1);
```

but this will not...

```
Object object = Main.getSession().get(MyStatus.class, 1);
```

I also did `instanceof` the `Object` returned above. It is clearly an `MyStatus` object and it has all correct data got from DB. My `Main` class is auto-generated by Intellij.

```
public class Main {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Session session = getSession();
        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Metamodel metamodel = session.getSessionFactory().getMetamodel();
            for (EntityType<?> entityType : metamodel.getEntities()) {
                final String entityName = entityType.getName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                for (Object o : query.list()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <mapping resource="/com/test/app/MyStatus.hbm.xml" class="com.test.app.models.MyStatus" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is the `Exception` thrown

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.MyStatus cannot be cast to com.test.MyStatus
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
```

Comment: Try to clean your project and recompile it from zero. Also clean your Servlet container. This usually happens when there are compilation or deployment issues.

Comment: I already did multiple times and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When you have `ClassCastException` on the same class (same name and package) it means that you are dealing with different `ClassLoaders`. 
If you print `MyStatus.class.getClassLoader()` and `object.getClass().getClassLoader()` you will see that they are different instances of ClassLoader.
This situation can happen when you have the same class in your Glassfish classpath and in your war.

2) Another weird thing is that you have `MyStatus` declared as `com.test.app.models.MyStatus` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` but the exception says `com.test.MyStatus`. These are two different classes but most likely are not related to the `ClassCastException` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast the result ?

```
MyStatus object = (MyStatus) Main.getSession().get(MyStatus.class, 1);
```

And as said @tsolakp, the error is weird, two packages seem to be loaded.