# java.lang.ClassCastException when casting to the same class - ClassLoader issues

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So, I using Hibernate and Spring MVC to build a webapp. I am been running a few queries on different tables and all work as intended, except for one table. I am be looking into this problem for a while, and realized it is a problem related to two different Java class loaders loading the same class.

I manage, in a way to fix the problem, by deploying the webapp it to a Tomcat server, but when I try to use Spring Boot, it simply doesn't work. For now, I can continue developing, but I rather use Spring Boot and also, I feel like I am just ignoring an issue that could somehow affect me in the future. The method that is causing everything, goes as follow.

```
public Usuario findById(String userId) {
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        return session.get(Usuario.class, userId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is my detailed stack trace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: application.model.Usuario cannot be cast to application.model.Usuario
at application.core.user.dao.implementation.UserDaoImplementation.findById(UserDaoImplementation.java:35)
at application.core.user.service.implementation.UserServiceImplementation.findById(UserServiceImplementation.java:17)
at application.security.UserDetailsApp.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsApp.java:34)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Although, I already know what the issue is, I still can't find a solution anywhere. I tried quite a few methods that I found, but to no avail. The error has not been fixed. Please, let me know if you need more information.

**Update**

The following question [getting ClassCastException when calling getSession().get() in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890662/getting-classcastexception-when-calling-getsession-get-in-hibernate), although similar it didn't solve my problem. What I am trying to achieve, is to be able to run it using Spring Boot. I managed to make it run in a Tomcat server, but Spring Boot just won't work.

**Update #2**

After digging a bit more, I realized the problem was a result of using Spring Dev Tools. After commenting out the maven dependency, the problem disappeared. Now, the problem is that I can't hot swap resources anymore. Has anyone faced an issue like this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting ClassCastException when calling getSession().get() in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890662/getting-classcastexception-when-calling-getsession-get-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, just solved it by using the correct `SessionFactory` version, in my case that I updated the sessionFactory to: `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` from:`org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`
(I'm using hibernate5)

Hope that helps,